# How to get ws-security username into Spring Integration message header

Tags: spring-integration

I am fairly new to Spring Integration.  How would I get the ws-security username token into the Spring Integration header.  I understand how to add Wss4jSecurityInterceptor to validate the username, but as this is an interceptor I have no access to the Mwssage object.  Once the message is unmarshalled into a JAB object, I lose the reference to the SOAP header.

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <!-- TODO use config property for host -->
                <prop key="${service.endpoint.url}/SNTWS/service/ConfigService">SOAPCompanyGateway</prop>
                <prop key="${service.endpoint.url}/SNTWS/service/CompanyService">SOAPCompanyGateway</prop>
                <prop key="${service.endpoint.url}/SNTWS/service/ContactService">SOAPContactGateway</prop>
                <!-- TODO add default mapping -->
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="interceptors">
            <array>

                <ref bean="SOAPSecurityInterceptor"></ref>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="SOAPSecurityInterceptor"
        class="com.ps.snt.ws.interceptor.SOAPSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken"/>
    </bean>
```

Can I use SPEL to access this information?  For example, can I do this (psuedo-code):

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="SOAPConfigRequestChannel"
        output-channel="SOAPRequestChannel">
        <int:header name="username" value="message.getSecurity().getUserName()" />
    </int:header-enricher>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the SOAP headers are mapped to message headers (by default) by the [DefaultSoapHeaderMapper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ws/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ws/DefaultSoapHeaderMapper.java).

Comment: Even things like ws-security?

Comment: I can't say I've used it myself, but it certainly looks like it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ws/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ws/DefaultSoapHeaderMapper.java#L79

Comment: I verified that DefaultSoapHEaderMapepr is returning the wsse:security header (which I can unmarshall later), but later in the flow the header is not set.

Comment: "later in the flow" - are you using persistent channels? You may need to unmarshall it earlier; I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging and track the headers to see where it is being dropped.

Comment: Found the issue - I needed to set the requestHeaderNames property of the mapper to * (all) or the specific headers I am looking for.  Thanks for a nudge in the right direction!